# How should I set up an app with only slight variations between models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm making a forum in Rails with the traditional `Topic` has many `Posts` setup.

However, the forum revolves around a forum game played by users that are pretty much just glorified Topics where the users play by taking turns posting.

In an effort to prototype my application, I created these models:

```
Topic has many Posts
Game has many GamePosts
InterestCheck has many InterestCheckPost
```

**How it works:**

- Users create an InterestCheck in the **Find A Game** subforum.
- When they find interested players, they start a Game in the **Games** subforum.
- And general discussion, news bulletins, and other convention message board use are made into **Topics**.

The reason I created new models for Games and InterestChecks is because I want to add specific metadata to them. For instance, Games can be tagged with various tags while Topics can't.

But it's obviously really ugly and repetitive because I'm recreating the same `Topic has many Posts` scenario for Games and InterestChecks. And it creates some really ugly routes like `new_game_game_post_path`.

**Question**

I've been stuck on how to implement this for a while, now. Topics, Games, and InterestChecks all have the same Topic/Post functionality, but I want to ensure that I can extend and add metadata on Games and InterestChecks which is why STI doesn't seem like the solution unless I'm mistakne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with **single table inheritance** and **polymorphic associations**.

**Single table inheritance**, which Rails natively supports, will let you have just one Topics table from which Games and InterestChecks can inherit.

Your Topic models will look like:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Game < Topic
  ...
end

class InterestCheck < Topic
  ...
end
```

Just add a `type` column to the Topic table. For example, `Game.all` is really just `Topic.where(:type => 'game')`.

**Polymorphic associations** will let all of your Topic models access the same Post table.

Your Post model will look like:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :postable, :polymorphic => true
  ...
end
```

And you support this in your Topic model with:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :as => :postable
end
```

And you'll need to add the `postable_type:string` and `postable_id:integer` to your Post table. Or you can accomplish the same with just `t.references :postable, :polymorphic => true` in your Post migration and it'll add the columns for you.

I haven't tested this.

Comment: Actually, you wouldn't even need polymorphic associations, just STI. Topic just needs `has_many :posts`. Since Games and InterestChecks descend from Topics, Posts still only has an association with the Topic model. You'd only use polymorphic associations if you decide to split Games and InterestChecks into their own models.